# Informatica real time event processing

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, real-time-data

I am new to Infromatica. I am looking for technology that will give me possibility to process big amounts of data (GB/s) in real time and do:

- real time event filtering and classification
- real time integration with different applications (sending alerts, SMS, emails)
- stateless and statefull event analysis
- data science stuff in real time (machine learning etc.)

I wonder if Informatica's technology stack is good choice. I found:

- Informatica PowerCenter Real time Edition (but this looks for me like some more advanced CDC)
- Informatica RulePoint (but this looks for me like some GUI for starting/stopping some predefined rules or creating your own rules for alerting purposes)

The question is, if above technologies, or any other from Informatica's technology stack, are able to do real time event processing and analysis (including statefull analyze and data science stuff- machine learing etc.). And if they do it efficiently.

Regards!